# How can I use python django

Tags: html, css, django, amazon-web-services, backend

I am sorry if the answer is obvious but I wasn't so sure and would like to get a clear answer on this, lets say I want to make a website with like chatbots in it, can I use the frontend to be html and css and than use python django to link backend with a database like AWS. If this is possible how exactly could I do this, also is there a better way to do this. I mostly want to do this as I want to learn more about backend coding, if there are better things to focus on please let me know. Thank you all.

I have made a front end with html/css but now I am trying to learn django to see what I can do further. I haven't done anything with JS or AWS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are in early stages of learning backend development, that is really great. At first I would recommend: try to learn how to connect your frontend to a backend (since you have a frontend at your hand).

There are many technologies to do backend development, **THE MOST IMPORTANT THING IS TO START DEVELOPING  FROM WHATEVER TECH YOU LIKE** , and stick to it until you learn how backends work and how it relates to the frontend, once you get to know how backends work, you will find that all backend tech work fundamentally the same, no matter what language.

A good advice I can share is, **for the moment**, forget about Making chatbots, deploying or managing Databases through AWS.

Just try to run the app(website) locally, and get a hang of how thing work, figure out how the local Database, backend and the frontend is related to one another.

If you are interested in Django Development, following link will be really helpful to get started:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/learn/server-side/django

A very good read if you are interested in back development:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/First_steps